# x86_64 assembly mmap syscall

Tags: assembly, x86-64, mmap, allocation, gnu-assembler

I try to make very simple memory allocator, but it gives me error on output, additionally the `print_sys_error` doesn't work properly. It works if I call it by this code:

```
_start:
    sub $16, %rsp # preallocate stack

    mov $20, %rdx
    mov $STDOUT, %rdi
    movq $_start.0, (%rsp)
    jmp print_sys_error
```

but it doesn't work in actual use.
code here:

```
.global _start

.text

_start:
    sub $16, %rsp # preallocate stack

    mov $0x1000, %rsi # allocate 4 KIB
    call alloc
    mov %rax, 8(%rsp) # save page address for later

    movq $_start.0, (%rsp) # prepearing for potential call of print_sys_error
    mov $STDOUT, %rdi

    cmpq $0, %rdx
    jne print_sys_error

    mov 8(%rsp), %rax # get back page address
    movb $0xff, (%rax)
    movb $0xff, 0xfff(%rax)

    mov $SYS_EXIT, %rax # exit successfully
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall

_start.0:
    sub $8, %rsp # stack got smaller after return

    mov $SYS_EXIT, %rax # fail successfully
    mov $1, %rdi
    syscall


### put file descriptor to %rdi and error code to %rdx (can't be over 34)
print_sys_error:
    call sys_error_to_str
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %rax
    syscall
    ret

### put error code to %rdx (can't be over 34)
### get string address in %rsi and string length in %rdx
sys_error_to_str:
    shl $4, %rdx
    mov error_table(%rdx), %rsi
    mov (error_table + 8)(%rdx), %rdx
    ret


### put new page size is rsi
### get error code in %rdx (0 if no error) and address in %rax (same as %rdx if error)
alloc:
    mov $SYS_MMAP, %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi # page address, zero so set by kernel
    mov $(PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC), %rdx # page access flags
    mov $(MAP_ANONYMOUS), %r10 # page/fd settings
    mov $-1, %r8 # fd (not used)
    xor %r9, %r9 # file offset (not used)
    syscall # page address in %rax

    cmpq $35, %rax # compare to error number (+1 as I see in glibc)
    jl alloc.0 # jump if error

    xor %rdx, %rdx # zero output error
    ret

alloc.0:

    mov %rax, %rdx # set output error
    ret


.data

.equ SYS_READ, 0 # for sys read `xor %rax %rax` can be used 
.equ SYS_WRITE, 1
.equ SYS_MMAP, 9
.equ SYS_EXIT, 60

.equ STDIN, 0
.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ STDERR, 2

.equ MAP_ANONYMOUS,    0x10
# some other map constants ...

.equ PROT_READ,             0x1
# some other prot constants ...

.section .data.sys_errors

.equ ERR_PERM, 1 # no permissions
.equ ERR_NOFILE, 2 # so such file or directory
# some other ERR constants


### each table element has address to the string and it's length, both values are qwords so each element has 16 bytes
error_table:
    .quad ERR_WRONG_STR
    .quad ERR_WRONG_STR_LEN

    .quad ERR_PERM_STR
    .quad ERR_PERM_STR_LEN
# ...


ERR_WRONG_STR:
    .asciz "wrong error"
    .equ ERR_WRONG_STR_LEN, . - ERR_WRONG_STR - 1

ERR_PERM_STR:
    .asciz "no permissions"
    .equ ERR_PERM_STR_LEN, . - ERR_PERM_STR - 1
# ...
```

the code is quite big for stack overflow question but I don't think it's very complicated.

I have tried looking online for more information about `mmap` syscall and about syscalls generally.
I don't remember exactly what I did with code to try fix it but I was messing with it pretty long.

Comment: Some Linux syscalls pass the arguments in a struct in memory, instead of in registers in the usual way.  The `?` appearing in https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md suggest that might be the case for mmap.  I don't recall off the top of my head where this is documented, though.

Comment: What error?  A [mcve] needs that info.  What does `strace ./a.out` say?  That'll show you what args you passed to the actual system call.

Comment: Also, I believe the test for a system call return value to be an error is if it's between -1 and -4095, or something like that.  Negative values are possible addresses on many architectures (though maybe not x86-64, since I think the "negative" address space is only used by the kernel).

Comment: @NateEldredge: `mmap` only has 6 args; on x86-64 they're passed normally in registers as per the calling convention.  The glibc `__mmap` function just does `mov r10, rcx` / `mov eax,9` / `syscall`.  (Well, it first tests and branches if R9 (`size_t offset`) has any bits set in the low 12).  Re: error returns, yes, `cmp $-4096, %rax` / `ja error` is the canonical way to test for error returns on any system call.  But on x86-64 Linux we can assume all high-half addresses are kernel, and thus won't be mmap return values, so `test %rax,%rax` / `js error` is valid based on that assumption.

Comment: In GAS, no need to define `SYS_mmap` yourself; `#include <sys/syscall.h>` for the right constants for the target.  (`gcc -c foo.S` runs it through CPP before assembling.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Perhaps you're seeing something about 32-bit systems where `mmap2` is used instead of `mmap`.  `mmap2` supports 64-bit file offsets even on 32-bit systems.  But it does that by having `offset` in units of 4096 byte pages, so `offset >> 12` which makes it fit in one 32-bit register still, so it doesn't need a special calling convention, other than the encoding of `offset`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or maybe just that mmap is declared specially in the headers.  That Chromium page indicates the tables are from parsing the headers somehow to obtain the types.  I'm pretty sure the Linux man pages document libc vs. kernel differences when they exist, including at least mentioning if there was a calling-convention indirection to a struct, so I've never had any use for those tables of system calls; the man pages (and the calling convention) already tell you everything.  `objdump -drwC -Mintel /lib/libc.so.6 | less` with an appropriate search is where I'd check next for weirdness.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe that is a substantially different question. HIs question was "Why this does not work" and not "Why do I need MAP_PRIVATE".  Also you just read my answer and are now attempting to close it once you know what the issue is? That was pretty sneaky buddy!

Comment: @NoleKsum: The linked question shows working asm and explains why it's necessary, and its very title points toward the answer to the bug in this question, which is nice for a dup.  (Assuming there's only one bug, the one you helpfully identified).  I'm not trying to be "sneaky"; Stack Overflow doesn't need multiple different questions about the right args to mmap for allocating anonymous memory.  Debugging questions ("this specific set of lines doesn't do what I want, how to fix?") typically have the lowest future value for SO, in terms of future readers.  This one at least narrows it to mmap.

Comment: @NoleKsum: Did you look for duplicates yourself before posting your answer?  I stopped looking at the first one that looked usable, which is I linked above.  I could have looked in more detail for another debugging question where this was the problem, but it's common that a good canonical duplicate about a problem like this isn't a debugging question, but rather a "why" question.  Anyway, I would guess there are probably more mmap questions, maybe some in C, where someone just passed `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and is asking why it didn't work.  You could have picked one of those if they have ok answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

It will not work with just `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

The documentation is clear:

```
The flags argument determines whether updates to the mapping are
visible to other processes mapping the same region, and whether 
updates are carried through to the underlying file. This behavior
is determined by including exactly one of the following  values
in flags:

   MAP_SHARED
          Share  this  mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes mapping the same region, and (in the case of
          file-backed mappings) are carried through to the underlying file.  (To precisely control when updates are carried through
          to the underlying file requires the use of msync(2).)

   MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE (since Linux 4.15)
          This  flag  provides  the  same behavior as MAP_SHARED except that MAP_SHARED mappings ignore unknown flags in flags.  By
          contrast, when creating a mapping using MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE, the kernel verifies all passed flags are known and fails the
          mapping  with  the error EOPNOTSUPP for unknown flags.  This mapping type is also required to be able to use some mapping
          flags (e.g., MAP_SYNC).

   MAP_PRIVATE
          Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file,
          and  are not carried through to the underlying file.  It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap()
          call are visible in the mapped region.

In addition, zero or more of the following values can be ORed in flags:
...
   MAP_ANONYMOUS 
   The mapping is not backed by any file;
```